How to properly center checked radio button?
I was styling a radio button and couldn't center the dot when checked. I tried using absolute positioning and grid display to center it, but I was unsuccessful. Can somebody tell me the reason and how to solve it?


/*--------styling using absolute poistionning---------*/
input[type="radio"]#id2{
    appearance: none;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 1.6rem;
    width: 1.6rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    border:2px solid rgb(18, 141, 223);
}

input[type="radio"]#id2::after{
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(0.1rem,0.1rem);
    content:"";
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 1.2rem;
    width: 1.2rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgb(18, 141, 223);
}

input[type="radio"]#id2:checked::after{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: ease 450ms;
}

/*-----------------styling using grid----------*/

input[type="radio"]#id1 {
    appearance: none;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 1.6rem;
    width: 1.6rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    border:2px solid rgb(18, 141, 223);
}

input[type="radio"]#id1::after{
    content:"";
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 1.2rem;
    width: 1.2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgb(18, 141, 223);
}

input[type="radio"]#id1:checked::after{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: ease 450ms;
}
<label for="id1">using grid layout</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="transport" id="id1">
<label for="id2">using absolute positionning</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="transport" id="id2">



I have tried both ways without success.

Your question isn't entirely clear, but I assume you're talking about centring the dot inside the circle? The grid layout one looks centred to me in Firefox. Depending on page zoom the absolutely positioned one sometimes looks centred. Have you thought about using an SVG and just change the fill colour of the dot?

If you change height and width to:
height: 1.15rem;
width: 1.15rem;
in the ::after selector, is this what you want ?

@miken32 you are correct have not notice that. Even in Chrom the grid layout looks centered depending on zoom values. Did not know about the possibility for using svg will check that as well

Use an easier way


input[type="radio"] {
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 1.6rem;  /* size */
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  padding: .1rem;  /* gap */
  color: rgb(18, 141, 223); /* color */
  border: 2px solid;
  transition: .2s;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked {
  background: currentColor content-box;
}
<input type="radio" name="transport">
<input type="radio" name="transport">




Your 1.2rem convert to a nonstandard 19.19px which is difficult for a browser to try to position. Try changing your dot size to 1.125rem (18px) and your radio size to 1.625rem (26px). For the position:absolute one, add top and negative transform: translate()


/*--------styling using absolute poistionning---------*/
input[type="radio"]#id2{
    appearance: none;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 1.625rem;
    width: 1.625rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    border:2px solid rgb(18, 141, 223);
}

input[type="radio"]#id2::after{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    content:"";
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 1.125rem;
    width: 1.125rem;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    line-height: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgb(18, 141, 223);
}

input[type="radio"]#id2:checked::after{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: ease 450ms;
}

/*-----------------styling using grid----------*/

input[type="radio"]#id1 {
    appearance: none;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 1.625rem;
    width: 1.625rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    border:2px solid rgb(18, 141, 223);
}

input[type="radio"]#id1::after{
    content:"";
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 1.125rem;
    width: 1.125rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgb(18, 141, 223);
}

input[type="radio"]#id1:checked::after{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: ease 450ms;
}
<label for="id1">using grid layout</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="transport" id="id1">
<label for="id2">using absolute positionning</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="transport" id="id2">




Still depending on the zoom and screen size it may look centered or not
